# Каждому Thread свои переменные, даже если сами Thread одинаковые

Tags: delphi, многопоточность

Есть код для потоков. И создание нескольких потоков с разными входными параметрами. Как определить каждому потоку свои локальные переменные?
Сейчас делаю это следующим образом:

```
  ThreadDead = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(startnum: integer; step: integer; endnum: integer);
  end;

var
  th1, th2: ThreadDead;
  mut: THandle;

ThreadVar
  sn, stp, en: integer;

constructor ThreadDead.Create(startnum, step, endnum: integer);
begin
  inherited Create(false);
  FreeOnTerminate:=True;
  sn:=startnum;
  stp:=step;
  en:=endnum;
end;

procedure ThreadDead.Execute;
begin
  while sn<en do
  begin
    WaitForSingleObject(mut,infinite);
    form1.out.Lines.Add(inttostr(sn));
    sn:=sn+stp;
    ReleaseMutex(mut);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  mut:=CreateMutex(nil,false,'');
  th1:=ThreadDead.Create(0, 2, 100);
  th2:=ThreadDead.Create(1, 2, 100);
  th1.Execute;
  th2.Execute;
end;
```

В результате вывод получается следующий: 1, 3, 5, ... , 95, 97, 99.
Будьте добры, натолкните на путь решения проблемы.
Ожидаемый вывод: 0, 1, 2, ... , 97, 98, 99.

Comment: Сделать их членами класса потока.

Comment: @SlavaZhuyko Там не только это :) Еще обращение к VCL из потока и лишний вызов Thread.Execute.

Comment: @SlavaZhuyko, сделал, как вы указали - теперь выводятся все числа. Только потоки отрабатывают сначала один, затем другой. Это из-за маленького количества итераций или некорректно использую mutex? Сделал задержку между итерациями - изменений нет.

Comment: @kami, в данной программе обращение потока к VCL не критично, но впредь буду с подобными действиями аккуратнее. В `inherited Create(false);` значение изменил, теперь `Execute`, кажется, оправдан.

Comment: Внешний вызов execute не оправдан вообще никогда. Этот метод начинает выполняться автоматически при старте потока. Собственно, это и есть "поток" с т.з. Delphi и он будет вызван самостоятельно.  А по поводу "не критично" - никогда так не говорите при работе с VCL<->поток. Только через Synchronize, Queue, Post/SendMessage. Кстати, поочередность действий двух потоков вам никто не гарантирует, в т.ч. и Mutex. Разве что на системах до Win Vista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sn, stp, en: integer;` перенести в раздел `private` класса потока - у каждого потока будут собственные локальные переменные.
`CloseHandle(mut);` убрать подальше от создания потоков (убрал в метод `FormDestroy`) - иначе потоки не успевают отработать - отсутствие mutex'а не позволяет.
Вывод информации на форму вынести в отдельный метод потока и вызывать его (метод) через Synchronize `Synchronize(outAdd);`

```
procedure ThreadDead.outAdd;
begin
  form1.out.Lines.Add(inttostr(sn));
end;
```

в ином случае форма становится недоступной, пока потоки осуществляют вывод. К тому же, вывод может оказаться некорректным.